# Finding parent documents based on a child ID

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, left-join, grouping

Suppose I have the following schemas

```
let TutorialQuizSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    groups: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group' }]
});

let GroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    members: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    responses: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Response' }]
});

let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        first: String,
        last: String
    }
});
```

Given a user ID, is it possible to query all the tutorial quizzes with all the groups that have the user as one of its members?

I'm new to aggregation, but I think it would be something like this

```
TutorialQuiz.aggreggate([
    {
        $unwind: '$groups'
    },
    { 
        $lookup: {
            from: 'groups',
            localField: 'groups',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'group'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$group'
    },
    {
        $match: { 
            'group.members': { $in: [req.user._id] } 
        }
    }
]).exec((err, data) => {
    // etc
})
```

If I am correct, my only problem with this is that the data comes out flattened. Is it possible to unflatten it to maintain the hierarchical structure (like if we were just doing a `find` + `populate` query) ?

Note: if there is better/easier way to do this, I am open to suggestions also.

Comment: What is your mongo server version ?

Comment: @Veeram It should be the latest. If not, I can always update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `$lookup` objectIds directly without `$unwind`ing  and use `$filter` instead of second `$unwind` inside the `$addFields` stage to filter the group on presence of `user_id` value in the `members` array in 3.4 version.

Something like

```
TutorialQuiz.aggreggate([
    { 
        $lookup: {
            from: 'groups',
            localField: 'groups',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'group'
        }
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
         group: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$group",
               as: "group",
               cond: { $in: [ req.user._id, "$$group.members" ] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```